# Message queueing for mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, message-queue

How would you implement message queueing for modile devices (Android, iOS)?
I mean devices which are located far from each other and so are supposed to connect via Internet.
The solution should guarantee delivery and (optionally) be transactional.

**Preamble:**
There's a fully functional proprietary message bus on Windows, with transport layer built over MSMQ and with no dedicated router/broker (nodes communicate directly using known *queue names*). We use this bus in our Intranet, behind hardware and software firewalls, and so do not care much about security.
And now we need to move from Windows to Android and from Intranet to Internet because the model of our business is going to change soon. It's not a problem to port C# code of the bus itself (thanks to Xamarin), but the implementation of its *transport level* should definitely change because there's no MSMQ in Android or iOS :)
For the moment we are thinking about RabbitMQ, Kafka, ZeroMQ, and even PubNub and Magnet Message. Of course we do not want to implement transport level by ourselves - that's a too monumental task.

Any advices appreciated!